# Automapper - mapping InnerDestination to OuterSource

Tags: c#, automapper

I've followed the nested example from the Automapper Wiki but I'm having some trouble extending it. In the code below, I'm trying to map InnerDest2 to OuterSource. Specifically, I want InnerDest2.Value to be populated with OuterSource.Value but when I run, InnerDest2 comes back as null. I'm sure there is something simple I'm missing, but I just can't figure it out.

Any ideas?

```
namespace AutomapNestTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ConfigureAutomapper();
            var source = new OuterSource
            {
                Value = 5,
                Inner = new InnerSource { OtherValue = 15 },
            };
            var dest = new OuterDest();

            AutoMapper.Mapper.Map(source, dest);
        }

        private static void ConfigureAutomapper()
        {
            AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.CreateMap<OuterSource, OuterDest>();
                cfg.CreateMap<InnerSource, InnerDest>();
                cfg.CreateMap<OuterSource, InnerDest2>();
            });
        }
    }

    public class OuterSource
    {
        public int Value { get; set; }
        public InnerSource Inner { get; set; }
    }

    public class InnerSource
    {
        public int OtherValue { get; set; }
    }

    public class OuterDest
    {
        public int Value { get; set; }
        public InnerDest Inner { get; set; }
        public InnerDest2 Inner3 { get; set; }
    }

    public class InnerDest
    {
        public int OtherValue { get; set; }
    }
    public class InnerDest2
    {
        public int Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mapping an `OuterSource` object to an `OuterDesc` object. There is a mapping configuration from `OuterSource` to `InnerDest2` but there is no property of type `OuterSource` in`OuterSource` itself so there is no way for the property`Inner3` in `OuterDest` to be mapped from anything.

If you need the `source.Value` to be mapped to `dest.Inner3.Value`, you would have to do another mapping explicitly. First declare the variable:

```
var innerDest2 = new InnerDest2();
```

After this, do the mapping and set the `dest.Inner3`:

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.Map(source, innerDest2);
dest.Inner3 = innerDest2;
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks. I guess I thought that because both OuterSource and InnerDest2 both had Value properties that it would just "automagically" pick that up in the 3rd CreateMap.